# How to call multiple bash command and ssh in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

I want to do the following commands in ruby.

1. ssh into another computer using `ssh example@example`
2. set source file `source ~/.profile`
3. `cd to/some/folder`
4. call my shell script with parameters, a json formatted string ,`./my_script.sh my_hash.to_json`

However I am facing these problems:
I call them in one line using backticks, it works, but it is a very bad practice in my opinion because it is not readable nor it is maintainable.

On the other hand, when I call `my_hash.to_json`, the resulted string has non-escaped double quotes, How do I escape them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to view this [tutorial](http://www.heatware.net/ruby-rails/how-to-ssh-to-server-ruby-part-i/) for ssh with ruby. then make a shell script and move it to server and then execute like a single command.

create a single shell script file for example `script1` and then execute it at once instead of executing each command individually.

**open file** script1 using any editor.

**copy all** commands to `script1` (each command in new line).

`script1` file should look like this

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh example@example
source ~/.profile
cd to/some/folder
```

**save file**

**make this file executable** using `chmod +x script`

**execute** it in ruby like this `[backtick]./script1[backtick]`

**note:** copy `script1` to usr/bin to avoid "./" and then try command only `script1`.

**Reference** for passing arguments in shell script is [here](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0130.php).